# Powershell | Bypassing Syntax Rules Applying to Serial Command

Tags: powershell, serial-port, midi

I have a PS script written to apply some basic configuration to a device over a COM connection. After some user input is recorded, it is used to format a minified java string to send to the device over USB. My issue is that powershell is applying syntax rules to this minified javascript string when I don't want it. I can sucefully send command to the device if they don't contain the javascript, stuff like device Restart etc work fine.

I'm unsure how to work around this, does anyone have a simple solution?

Here's the errors when I try to run it:

```
At line:146 char:22
+     $port.Write("3,{"bankName":"$bankName","bankId":"0","footswitches ...
+                      ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:146 char:22
+ ... .Write("3,{"bankName":"$bankName","bankId":"0","footswitches":[{"name ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'bankName":"$bankName","bankId":"0","footswitches":[{"name":"$FS1
"},{"name":"$FS2"},{"name":"$FS3"},{"name":"$FS4"},{"name":"$FS5"},{"name":"$FS6"}
]}~"' in expression or statement.
At line:126 char:1
+ {
+ ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:146 char:172
+ ... ,{"name":"$FS3"},{"name":"$FS4"},{"name":"$FS5"},{"name":"$FS6"}]}~")
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:149 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordExcep 
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

Here's the full script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Bridge Namer'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,400)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,320)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,320)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$cancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'What Bank Number do you want to Re-Name?'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBoxbankNumber = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBoxbankNumber.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$textBoxbankNumber.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxbankNumber)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'New Bank Name:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBoxbankName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBoxbankName.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,90)
$textBoxbankName.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxbankName)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,120)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$label.Text = 'Footswitch 1 Name:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBoxFS1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBoxFS1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,140)
$textBoxFS1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxFS1)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$label.Text = 'Footswitch 2 Name:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBoxFS2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBoxFS2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,140)
$textBoxFS2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxFS2)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,170)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$label.Text = 'Footswitch 3 Name:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBoxFS3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBoxFS3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,190)
$textBoxFS3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxFS3)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,170)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$label.Text = 'Footswitch 4 Name:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBoxFS4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBoxFS4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,190)
$textBoxFS4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxFS4)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,220)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$label.Text = 'Footswitch 5 Name:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBoxFS5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBoxFS5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,240)
$textBoxFS5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxFS5)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,220)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$label.Text = 'Footswitch 6 Name:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBoxFS6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBoxFS6.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,240)
$textBoxFS6.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxFS6)

$form.Topmost = $true

$form.Add_Shown({$textBoxbankNumber.Select()})
$form.Add_Shown({$textBoxbankName.Select()})
$form.Add_Shown({$textBoxFS1.Select()})
$form.Add_Shown({$textBoxFS2.Select()})
$form.Add_Shown({$textBoxFS3.Select()})
$form.Add_Shown({$textBoxFS4.Select()})
$form.Add_Shown({$textBoxFS5.Select()})
$form.Add_Shown({$textBoxFS6.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $bankNumber = $textBoxbankNumber.Text   
    $bankName = $textBoxbankName.Text    
    $FS1 = $textBoxFS1.Text   
    $FS2 = $textBoxFS2.Text 
    $FS3 = $textBoxFS3.Text
    $FS4 = $textBoxFS4.Text  
    $FS5 = $textBoxFS5.Text
    $FS6 = $textBoxFS6.Text

    $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM6,9600,None,8,one
    $port.DtrEnable = "true"
    $port.open()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
    $port.Write("0,RSET~")
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
    $port.Write("1,DTXR~")
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
    $port.Write("2,bankSettings,$bankNumber~")
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
    $port.Write("3,{"bankName":"$bankName","bankId":"0","footswitches":[{"name":"$FS1"},{"name":"$FS2"},{"name":"$FS3"},{"name":"$FS4"},{"name":"$FS5"},{"name":"$FS6"}]}~")
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
    $port.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well without a suggested serial port string a correct answer is hard to construct. I just double quoted your quotes in my example (That will fix the PS part). Since your implied output statement is valid java string, i somehow guessed your desired output.

```
    $FS1 = "a"
    $FS2 = "b"
    $FS3 = "c"
    $FS4 = "d"
    $FS5 = "e"
    $FS6 = "f"
    $bankName = "bar"
    $port.Write("3,{""bankName"":""$bankName"",""bankId"":""0"",""footswitches"":[{""name"":""$FS1""},{""name"":""$FS2""},{""name"":""$FS3""},{""name"":""$FS4""},{""name"":""$FS5""},{""name"":""$FS6""}]}~")
```

OutPut

```
3,{"bankName":"bar","bankId":"0","footswitches":[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"},{"name":"d"},{"name":"e"},{"name":"f"}]}~
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I thought I'd already answered this. I got around this problem by masking the quotations in this way:

```
$port.Write("3,{`"bankName`":`"$bankName`",`"bankId`":`"0`",`"footswitches`":[{`"name`":`"$FS1`"},{`"name`":`"$FS2`"},{`"name`":`"$FS3`"},{`"name`":`"$FS4`"},{`"name`":`"$FS5`"},{`"name`":`"$FS6`"}]}~")
```